# OPC-UA Function of "UA_ReadRequest_deleteMembers" Error Problem

Tags: c, opc-ua, open62541

Hello Everyone i have one question

I Using OPC-UA for client, I have some problem

This is Problem code

```
UA_ReadRequest requestPos;
UA_ReadRequest_init(&requestPos);
UA_ReadValueId idPos;
UA_ReadValueId_init(&idPos);
idPos.attributeId = UA_ATTRIBUTEID_VALUE;
idPos.nodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(6, (char*)"::AsGlobalPV:gMotionPos");
requestPos.nodesToRead = &idPos;
requestPos.nodesToReadSize = 1;

UA_ReadResponse responsePos = UA_Client_Service_read(client, requestPos);

UA_ReadRequest_deleteMembers(&requestPos);
```

I want to clear `UA_ReadRequest requestPos;`, so I use `UA_ReadRequest_deleteMembers(&requestPos);`, but compiler said: "****.exe caused a breakpoint. Occur ". I can't understand this error.

[image]

Comment: Which OPC UA SDK are you using there? Is this the foundation c stack, or open62541, or...?

Comment: I using open62541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a non-owning string nodeid. The delete members will free the memory used, even though it's not owned resulting in a memory corruption.

Replace the UA_NODEID_STRING() with UA_NODEID_STRING_ALLOC().